# Node.js Mongodb toggling boolean operator doesnt work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hello Im having a weird issue

Ive looked in a few previous questions but ive ran into an issue

Basically I have a document containing a boolean

This boolean is called enabled

Id like to switch it using the findOneAndUpdate function

```
{ $set: { enabled: { $not: "$enabled" } } }
```

This is what ive come to according to previous questions

However when I attempt it this is the result

```
enabled: { '$not': '$enabled' }
```

Here is my full code

```js
db.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: "Sample"
}, {
    $set: {
        enabled: {
            $not: "$enabled"
        }
    }
}, {
    new: true
}, function(err, result) {})
```

Comment: Share [reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please.

Comment: You are trying to update the status of the enabled field to the opposite of the current value right? Like if the current state is false, then change to true and vice-versa?

Comment: Yes if its true it will become false if it is false it will become true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use the [$not](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/not/#-not--aggregation-) aggregation operator inside of a legacy update.

In order to use aggregation operators you will need to use [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/#updates-with-aggregation-pipeline).

For your example, this should be as simple as wrapping the update in an array like:

```
db.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: "Sample"
},[{
    $set: {
        enabled: {
            $not: "$enabled"
        }
    }
}], {
    new: true
}, function(err, result) {})
```

Comment: If there is a document in the collection that doesn't have an enabled field, or has an enabled field with a non-boolean value, what should happen?

Comment: That wont be the case 

thank you a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **$bit** operator to toggle the value of the enabled field.

```
db.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: "Sample"
}, {
   { $bit: { enabled: { xor: 1 } } }
}, {
    new: true
}, function(err, result) {})
```

On each update, the value **enabled** will toggle (1 to 0, 0 to 1).

Alternatively, you can use the set method as thus:

```
 db.findOneAndUpdate({
            _id: "Sample"
        }, [{
    $set: {
        enabled: {
            $not: "$enabled"
        }
    }
}], {
      new: true
        }, function(err, result) {})
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a boolean ? I cannot tranisition the entire DB to use integers

Comment: I made an update to the answer

Comment: I tried it but I got this weird result:

 enabled: { '$expr': [Object] }